# Woocommerce reset_variations link not resetting after I converted drop-downs to radio buttons

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress, woocommerce

I used the code below to convert my Woocommerce variations into radio buttons and style them up how I needed. However, the "clear" button with the class of reset_variations doesn't actually reset the value of the original select options.

Can someone advise on how to clear or reset both the original select (which is hidden by CSS) and the radio buttons?

```
//THIS CHANGES THE WOOCOMMERCE SELECT ITEMS INTO RADIO BUTTONS */
function variation_radio_buttons($html, $args) {
  $args = wp_parse_args(apply_filters('woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_args', $args), array(
    'options'          => false,
    'attribute'        => false,
    'product'          => false,
    'selected'         => false,
    'name'             => '',
    'id'               => '',
    'class'            => '',
    'show_option_none' => __('Choose an option', 'woocommerce'),
 ));

  if(false === $args['selected'] && $args['attribute'] && $args['product'] instanceof WC_Product) {
    $selected_key     = 'attribute_'.sanitize_title($args['attribute']);
    $args['selected'] = isset($_REQUEST[$selected_key]) ? wc_clean(wp_unslash($_REQUEST[$selected_key])) : $args['product']->get_variation_default_attribute($args['attribute']);
  }

  $options               = $args['options'];
  $product               = $args['product'];
  $attribute             = $args['attribute'];
  $name                  = $args['name'] ? $args['name'] : 'attribute_'.sanitize_title($attribute);
  $id                    = $args['id'] ? $args['id'] : sanitize_title($attribute);
  $class                 = $args['class'];
  $show_option_none      = (bool)$args['show_option_none'];
  $show_option_none_text = $args['show_option_none'] ? $args['show_option_none'] : __('Choose an option', 'woocommerce');

  if(empty($options) && !empty($product) && !empty($attribute)) {
    $attributes = $product->get_variation_attributes();
    $options    = $attributes[$attribute];
  }

  $radios = '<div class="variation-radios d-flex">';



  if(!empty($options)) {
    if($product && taxonomy_exists($attribute)) {
      $terms = wc_get_product_terms($product->get_id(), $attribute, array(
        'fields' => 'all',
      ));



      foreach($terms as $term) {
              $image = get_field('attribute_image', $term->taxonomy . '_' . $term->term_id );

               $description = get_field('attribute_description', $term->taxonomy . '_' . $term->term_id );

        if(in_array($term->slug, $options, true)) {
          $radios .= '<div class="flex-item"><label class="nada" for="'.esc_attr($term->slug).'"><img src="'. $image .'"><input type="radio" name="'.esc_attr($name).'" value="'.esc_attr($term->slug).'" '.checked(sanitize_title($args['selected']), $term->slug, false).' id="'.esc_attr($term->slug).'"><div class="caption"><h2>'.esc_html(apply_filters('woocommerce_variation_option_name', $term->name)).'</h2><p>'. $description .'</p></div></label></div>';
        }
      }
    } else {
      foreach($options as $option) {
              $image = get_field('attribute_image', $term->taxonomy . '_' . $term->term_id );
               $description = get_field('attribute_description', $term->taxonomy . '_' . $term->term_id );


        $checked    = sanitize_title($args['selected']) === $args['selected'] ? checked($args['selected'], sanitize_title($option), false) : checked($args['selected'], $option, false);
        $radios    .= '<div class="flex-item"><label class="nada" for="'.sanitize_title($option).'" '.$checked.'><img src="'. $image .'"><input type="radio" name="'.esc_attr($name).'" value="'.esc_attr($option).'" id="'.sanitize_title($option).'<div class="caption"><h2>'.esc_html(apply_filters('woocommerce_variation_option_name', $option)).'</h2><p>'. $description .'</p></div></label></div>';
      }
    }
  }

  $radios .= '</div>';

  return $html.$radios;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_html', 'variation_radio_buttons', 20, 2);
```

And the JQuery to pass the value from the original select to the radio button

```
 <script> // pass value to the select //
  jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {

  $(document).on('change', '.variation-radios input', function() {
    $('select[name="'+$(this).attr('name')+'"]').val($(this).val()).trigger('change'); 

  });



});
</script>
```

Here's the sample product. I unhid the select boxes to show how the reset is not working:

http://dev.chrislamdesign.com/vr/product/test/